# HasOneSetAssociationMixin is not a function typescript

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

sequelize set and create always get this error at type script sequelize versions 7 alpha

HasOneSetAssociationMixin is not a function typescript

here is acode

```
import {
    CreationOptional,
    DataTypes, HasOneCreateAssociationMixin, HasOneSetAssociationMixin,
    InferAttributes,
    InferCreationAttributes,
    Model,
    NonAttribute
} from "@sequelize/core";
import {Attribute, AutoIncrement, HasOne, NotNull, PrimaryKey} from "@sequelize/core/decorators-legacy";

export class Person extends Model<InferAttributes<Person>, InferCreationAttributes<Person>> {
    @Attribute(DataTypes.INTEGER)
    @AutoIncrement
    @PrimaryKey
    declare id: CreationOptional<number>;

    @HasOne(() => DrivingLicense, /* foreign key */ 'ownerId')
    declare drivingLicense?: NonAttribute<DrivingLicense>;

    declare setperson:HasOneSetAssociationMixin<DrivingLicense,'ownerId'>
}

export class DrivingLicense extends Model<InferAttributes<DrivingLicense>, InferCreationAttributes<DrivingLicense>> {
    @Attribute(DataTypes.INTEGER)
    @AutoIncrement
    @PrimaryKey
    declare id: CreationOptional<number>;

    // This is the foreign key
    @Attribute(DataTypes.INTEGER)
    @NotNull
    declare ownerId: number;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.